# How to avoid general weakness when taking antibiotics

Tags: antibiotics

After taking antibiotics for a couple of days, I feel a general sense of weakness in my body. This includes physical weakness (tiredness, shortness of breath) and mental weakness (difficulty of performing normal cognitive tasks, impossibility of performing more difficult ones).

Is there a way to reduce this general weakness when on antibiotics, so as to remain as close to normal functioning as possible?

Comment: Why are you taking antibiotics? The first step would be to avoid [unnecessary antibiotic prescriptions](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20170529-the-reasons-you-can-never-be-anonymous-again).

Comment: I have a severe infection that is causing internal bleeding.

Comment: Okay, that's a very good reason to be taking antibiotics.

Comment: I would go to your doctor and ask them this question. Fatigue and tiredness might be one of the side effects of the specific antibiotics you are taking.

Comment: @Narusan Those side effects are exactly what I'm trying to reduce, hence my question

Comment: I don't think that possible, switching the antiobiotics might be a easier way of alleviating your issue. But you'll need to talk to your doctor about this.

Comment: maybe reason not antibiotics, but infection